# Negation of function reference in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

We can filter all items in a list that are also contained in another list by

```
list.filter(otherList::contains)
```

However, I want to filter all items in a list that are NOT contained in the other list. How can I negate the above?

Ofc, I can pass a lambda, for example

```
list.filter { !otherList.contains(it) }
```

but I looking for a better Kotlin-way approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `filterNot` to filter out items that are not contained in another list. This returns a list of elements for which the predicate yields `false`.

```
val filteredList = list.filterNot { otherList.contains(it) }
```

The operation has a time complexity of O(n*m), where n is the size of the original list and m is the size of the other list. If performance becomes an issue due to large lists, consider converting otherList to a HashSet, which would allow for constant-time lookups:

```
val setFromOtherList = otherList.toHashSet()
val filteredList = list.filterNot { setFromOtherList.contains(it) }
```

The above code will perform faster for large lists because checking membership in a `HashSet` is generally much quicker than checking membership in a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `filterNot()`, there's a more concise way of phrasing a lambda solution:

```
list.filter{ it !in otherList }
```

`in` and `!in` are simply [syntactic sugar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#in-operator)  for calls to `contains()`.  (I find them easier to read — especially for the negated case — as well as being more concise, and I'm surprised they're not more widely used.)

Similarly, lambdas are arguably easier to read than method references.  (Any difference in performance is likely to be insignificant, and readability is important.)  Also, lambdas are a lot more flexible — as this question demonstrates!

Comment: I definitely prefer your approach. Thanks for insights, going to change my code now. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `filterNot{}` works for you

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not.html